# Issue Extracting Dollar Amounts from Web Scraped Text

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract dollar amounts from a web page that I am scraping using Python and Selenium. I have implemented the following code to scrape data from a webpage and extract dollar amounts from the text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import csv
import re

url = 'https://skinsmonkey.com/trade'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

scroll_script = """
var element = arguments[0];
element.scrollTop += 681;  
"""

time.sleep(1)
scrollable_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.trade-inventory:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)')

csv_file_path = 'output.csv'
with open(csv_file_path, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Item Text', 'Alt Text', 'Price'])

while True:
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item-card__body')
    
    for element in elements:
        
        if element.text.strip() != "Quick View":
            item_text = element.text.replace('\n', '')
            
            price_matches = re.findall(r'\$([\d,.]+)', item_text)
            price = "Price not found"
            if price_matches:
                price = ', '.join(match[0] for match in price_matches)
        
            img_elements = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
            alt_text = ""
            for img_element in img_elements:
                alt_text = img_element.get_attribute('alt')
                if alt_text:
                    break
            
            with open(csv_file_path, mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow([item_text, alt_text, price])
    
    for _ in range(2):  
        driver.execute_script(scroll_script, scrollable_box)
        time.sleep(1)  
    
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, I'm facing issues with the regular expression re.findall(r'$([\d,.]+)', item_text) not correctly extracting the dollar amounts from the scraped text. Can someone please help me identify the problem and provide a solution to extract the dollar amounts accurately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need regexp for this case. You can filter card elements with prices by getting elements, that contain inner element with class `item-card__price`.

And then you just get `innerText` property from card, image and price element.

```py
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="item-card__body" and .//*[contains(@class,"item-card__price")]]')))

    for element in elements:
            item_text = element.get_property('innerText').replace('\n', '')
            price_element = element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item-card__price')
            price = price_element.get_property('innerText')

            img_elements = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
            alt_text = ""
            for img_element in img_elements:
                alt_text = img_element.get_attribute('alt')
                if alt_text:
                    break

            with open(csv_file_path, mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow([item_text, alt_text, price])
```